# Can I get back lost ETH in splitting attempt?

Tags: wallets, ether, poloniex

Please can I have some info if I can get my lost ether back.

I had eth in presale wallet. I imported the presale json file on Ethereum Wallet 0.8.9.

That created a new wallet with correct amount of ether form presale wallet.

Than I have imported json file on ETC Wallet chrome extension. I recieved the same amount of ETC. Than I have sent that ETC on Poloniex ETC address. After that my ETH disappeared from Ethereum wallet.

Can anything be done to retrieve eth?

EDIT:
got ETH later along with ETC on Polo. interesting